# Can't figure out this stack output c++

Tags: c++

So I have a stack example I created following a tutorial using the stack library

```
stack<string> custs;
    custs.push("george");
    custs.push("louie");
    custs.push("florence");
   // cout << "size" << custs.size() << endl;
    if (!custs.empty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= custs.size(); i++) {
            cout << custs.top() << endl;
            custs.pop();
        }
    }
```

I ran this and got the output:
florence
louie

My question is why isn't it outputting George as well? The program outputs the top data then pops it. This means it should output Gorge then pop it after. Why doesn't this happen? initially the code was i < cust.size so I thought because i is not less than 1 it would not ouput. So I switched it to <= and it still doesn't output George. How come?

Comment: Hint: what is `custs.size()` after the first iteration?

Comment: Loops that deal with stacks are written as `while (!custs.empty()) { do_stuff; custs.pop(); }`, and not by using a `for` loop based on the size of the stack.

Comment: @dxiv so what is the for loop doing here then? The size is at 1 after we pop Louie. So the loop can't increment itself and go past the size of 1? and print George? Is that it? I thought as long as the condition is <= it will enter the loop? Or do I have a broken understanding of how a for loop works? I have never ran into this scenario with for loops before so its a bit of a confusion

Comment: @edo101 -- Take a very simple case -- your stack has 1 item in it.  Follow your logic.

Comment: @edo101 `The size is at 1 after we pop Louie` Yes, but `i` is already `2` at that point, so it is no longer true that `i <= size()` and the loop breaks without popping the last element.

Comment: @dxiv I was tracking i via VS studio. It told me i = 1 after we pop louie for some reason. Ah nvm. Yeah I guess VS just didn't track i properly. it didn't increment then compare it on the debug tracker. Which made me take it at face value. thanks. So it is 2 and 2 is not less than the size. Ah darn. Wish I ahd caught that earlier.

Comment: Thanks all. I mis tracked the value of i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a step by step explanation of what is happening so you can understand it better:

First, `i` starts as 0, and `custs.size()` returns 3. Since `0 <= 3` is `true`, the body of the loop executes, printing "florence" and removing it from the stack.

On the second iteration, `i` equals 1, and `custs.size()` returns 2, because you had 3 items but you removed one. Since `1 <= 2` is `true`, the body of the loop executes again, printing "louie" and removing it from the stack.

Then, `i` equals 2, and `custs.size()` returns 1, because you already removed 2 elements. Since `2 <= 1` is `false`, the body of the loop *doesn't* execute, and the loop ends.

As you can see, the problem is that your loop's condition changes on each iteration. There are a couple of ways to fix this:

```
int s = custs.size();
for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
    cout << custs.top() << endl;
    custs.pop();
}
```

By doing that, you store the original size of the stack, so you can iterate without problems.

Another solution would be to check if the stack is empty on each iteration with a `while` loop:

```
while (!custs.empty()) {
    cout << custs.top() << endl;
    custs.pop();
}
```

By doing that, you check if there are any elements left to print each time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you. marked as clean well written out explanation. Thank you kindly!

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped you

Answer (score 4):

It is because you are both increasing `i` and reducing the size of the stack in the loop.

You can rewrite your loop like this:

```cpp
while (!custs.empty()) {
    cout << custs.top() << endl;
    custs.pop()
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that `i <= custs.size();` is almost always wrong. The `<=` will allow a range of  [0, `custs.size()`] and that is one too many.

Comment: @Sami Sallinen so what is the for loop doing here then? The size is at 1 after we pop Louie. So the loop can't increment itself and go past the size of 1? and print George? Is that it? I thought as long as the condition is <= it will enter the loop? Or do I have a broken understanding of how a for loop works? I have never ran into this scenario with for loops before so its a bit of a confusion

Comment: @user4581301 how is it wrong? I am telling it to make sure it hits 1 since 1 is the size of the custs after we pop Louie

Comment: @edo101 HINT: `custs.size()` is not constant... every time you call `custs.pop()` the value changes.

Comment: @edo101 Look up "off-by-one error" to find out why `<=` is almost always wrong.

Comment: Should it be `while (! custs.empty())` ?

Comment: Say the there are 5 items in the container. The size will be 5. `for (int i = 0; i <= custs.size(); i++)` would be `for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)`. The loop will iterate with `i`=0,1,2,3,4, and 5 before `i` is not less than or equal to 5. That's 6 iterations on a container with 5 items.

Comment: @SethMMorton I know that the size is not constant. After we pop Louie the stack has a size of 1. at this point the value of i is 1. Why won't it go through the loop as i have set it to i<=cust.size() which means the loop should continue no?

Comment: @edo101 When the size is 1 `i` is 2.

Comment: And on top of what @user4581301 just wrote, `custs.size()` was also decreasing on each loop itertation, making the situation worse.

Comment: @edo101 Stop thinking about the code and work through the logic on a piece of paper. Build yourself a table tracking `i` and the contents of `custs` for each iteration. Visualizing the problem often helps makes things clear.

Comment: @edo  You are burning the candle at both ends.  The size is decreasing, and `i` is increasing.  When the two ends meet, `i` is greater than `size()`, thus the last element is not written.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah Yeah I guess VS just didn't track i properly. it didn't increment then compare it on the debug tracker. Which made me take it at face value. thanks. So it is 2 and 2 is not less than the size. Ah darn. Wish I had caught that earlier. THanks all. feel like hitting my face on my desk for not catching this earlier

Answer (score 1):

When you use for loop like this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= custs.size(); i++) {
            cout << custs.top() << endl;
            custs.pop();
        }
```

it loops directly till the size of stack which decreases in each iteration.
which in my opinion is the main reason your code is not working. I rewrite this as

```
int z =  custs.size() ;
 for(int i=0;i<=z;i++)
    {
        cout<<custs.top()<<endl;
        custs.pop();
    }
```

and it worked perfectly fine. In my opinion, the best approach is to use `while loop` like this

```
while(!custs.empty())
    {
        cout<<custs.top()<<endl;
        custs.pop();
    }
```

Comment: why would taken out the empty check from my code make it work? You revision is definitely more apt

Comment: The empty check has nothing to do with it. the loop will run 0 times if the stack is empty so it doesn't matter here. You can even add that but that will only increase the runtime of the program

Comment: yeah i just realized, you set size to variable that won't change instead of using size as the parameter for the for loop